# Java - how much space does anonymous object take?

Tags: java, heap-memory, anonymous-class

supposing the following scenario:

```
void thisIsCalledManyTimes(){
    // ....
    someObject.executeIfNecessary( new Runnable(){
         void run(){ //do sth here}
    });
}
```

how much space would the anonymous object take? I understand that each object anonymous obj would have a pointer to the same implementation of `run` in its method lookup table.

Comment: it'll take some space, why exactly do you want to know it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code of [Runnable](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Runnable.java.html) doesn't specify any fields, and so the anonymous class won't take any more space than an `Object`, with two differences. An inner class has an implicit reference to the outer class instance, so you would want to factor this in. It will also take copies of `final` variables referenced from the outer class.

Answer (score 4):

An anonymous class takes up much the same amount of space as a non-anonymous class.  All objects keep a reference to the class they are an instance of.

The only thing different about an anonymous class is that it will contain a reference to

- the outer class instance
- a copy of any final variables used.

Answer (score 1):

All instances of `run` will indeed share the same "pointer" to the method look-up table. However, the precise size of the object depends on the content of the `run` and the `...` above it. The anonymous class the compiler generates provides space for storing the variables referenced by the `run` method, in addition to space for storing a reference to the `this` object of the enclosing class.

For example,

```
private String name;

void thisIsCalledManyTimes(){
    final int value1 = 123;
    final double value2 = 456.789.
    someObject.executeIfNecessary( new Runnable(){
         void run(){
             System.out.println(name);   // Referenced through the enclosing "this"
             System.out.println(value1); // Variable will be inserted by the compiler
             System.out.println(value2); // Variable will be inserted by the compiler
         }
    });
}
```

reserves the space in the object to store `value1`, `value2`, and `this`; each instance of the anonymous object will get a copy of these variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use profiler to check size of your class' instance. It's rather small as there are no properties - it's just as large as instance of java.lang.Object. It depends on JVM version.

If you need to make this more efficent just do :

```
void thisIsCalledManyTimes(){
// ....
   if (someObject.isItNecessary()) {
     someObject.execute( new Runnable(){
         void run(){ //do sth here}
     });
   }
```

}

However I won't bother about this too much as this.